# Div background image not shrinking to fit despite using "background-size: cover"

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, background-size

Here's the original image (2880 x 900):
[image]

And here's how it appears on the rendered page (1280 x 500):
[image]

1280 x 500 is the dimension of the `<div>` that contains the image as its background. If you notice, the rendered background is getting cropped instead of shrinking to fit inside the div which is smaller than the original image. My understanding is that a `background-size: cover` is meant to scale the image up or down without cropping. Why is it not working?

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-header-div">
    <div class="page-header-div-image-blog" style="background: url(<?php echo $bannerurl ?>) no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="downarrow text-center downarrow1" onclick="scrollPage(this);"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-header-div { position: relative; }
.page-header-div-image-blog {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The exact same markup on another page works just fine! The two pages have the exact same tags used for the snippet. Is there no way to fix this issue through CSS? If so, how can one go about doing it using JS (I would really want to avoid that if at all possible).

Comment: you need `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Also, 2880 x 900 is a different aspect ratio than your div at 1280 x 500, so even when you use `contain` you will have a gap

Comment: You're right, contain doesn't work either. However, the same image fits just fine on another page with the same div dimensions which is what baffles me.

Comment: Is it so hard to check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) before asking such question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `background-size: contain;` instead and also set `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`.

From [MDN `background-size` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> **cover**: A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. **When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.**
>
> **contain**: A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Also note that, as @zgood pointed:

> 2880 x 900 is a different aspect ratio than your div at 1280 x 500, so event when you use contain you will have a gap

```css
div {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf8Wg.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

See also:

- [Scaling background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images) (MDN)

Comment: It's already set to no-repeat and I had already tried `contain` with no success before posting the question.

Comment: I understand there should be a gap but that's not what's happening. In my case, the image is simply being cropped which isn't what I want. The results are the same with contain as well.

Comment: @TheLearner So post a code snippet which can reproduce that issue.

Comment: @TheLearner _The exact same markup on another page works just fine!_ There must be something different... like a misspelled class name or invalid markup. You missing a CSS import on 1 page maybe?

Comment: Not sure what you want...I already posted the HTML and CSS of the affected piece.

Comment: @TheLearner We can't help you without seeing the code. Have you checked styles on that element in developer console?

Comment: Yes I did...they are identical and I am really confused as to which code you're asking for. I did post the code in my question – both HTML as well as the CSS. Anyways, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @TheLearner Post plain HTML code, not with PHP fragments. And the CSS you posted is not the whole CSS that is needed to reproduce your error, for example it doesn't event contain `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem. It turns out that I had my background-size declared before my background. See example:

DID NOT WORK:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background: url(../img/background.jpg) center center no-repeat;
```

WORKS:

```
background: url(../img/background.jpg) center center no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I had the same issue, and this worked for me. Very frustrating issue.  This should actually be the correct answer. Changing cover to contain won't do anything unless background-size is declared after background.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf8Wg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```